# Windows 10 sudden blank screen

Tags: windows-10, drivers, blank-screen

Lately i re-installed Windows 10 to get a fresh OS. After i have installed and updated everything including drivers, it worked fine until few hours later, screen went blank with no cursor or anything at all, just blank.

- Not necessarily a black screen, sometimes colored [black twice, dark green once]
- RAM LEDs indicated no activities although last time i was rendering some videos which means the whole OS stopped running (PC still on)
- Re-installed latest drivers (i don't think it's a driver issue)
- Video card is fine, i tested it on another machine for a whole 72 hours

What could be causing this problem?

Edit:

After i reset/restart PC, it works fine until another couple hours later.